# Using Zorn's Lemma x

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $Z=${$A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$: $A$ is closed under subtraction and $1\not\in A$}. Let $Z$ be paritial order with subset relation. Show $Z$ has a maximal 
element.

We will use Zorn's Lemma. My lecture notes say $\left\{ 0\right\}\in Z$. Why? Can you explain?

Comment: We show that $\{0\}\in Z$ to establish that $Z$ is not empty. We cannot use Zorn' s Lemma to obtain a maximal member of $Z$ unless we know that $Z$ has at least one member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $1\notin \{0\}$ and $0-0=0$ thus $\{0\}$ is closed under subtraction. i.e $\{0\}\in Z $
This shows that $Z$ is not empty, and therefor you can use Zorn's Lemma.

Hint, take the union of an ascending chain